# How to play rtsp streams in ubuntu?

Tags: vlc, streaming, mplayer, rtsp

More specifically, the question is how to play rtsp streams from addresses that have a question mark in them.

I.E: *rtsp://some.server.name:554/video_file.wmv?authstring=sOm3StrIN2==&param=3*

I have tried various media players, but couldn't stream the file. I know for sure this is not a server problem because I could stream a test video on that server that doesn't require an authentication.

 I was surprised that **vlc** couldn't handle such urls, so I tried **mplayer** but it couldn't play the streams either.

**mpv** was the first player in which I managed to play the test video I mentioned above, but I couldn't stream urls of the form I written above. With **mpv** I tried this command line:

```
mpv --http-header-fields='authstring:sOm3StrIN2==','param:3' \rtsp://some.server.name:554/video_file.wmv
```

and also tried adding the `--rtsp-transport=lavf|tcp|udp|http` option, but nothing worked.

Unfortunately, I know that such links (as wrote above) work with the windows media player, but I don't want to use wine or go over to windows (I have duel boot) just to watch a stream.

Answer (score 17):

For me the best player is ffmpeg:

```
ffplay rtsp://username:password@server:554/path
```

If authentication is not needed,

```
ffplay rtsp://server:554/path
```

Comment: The command works quite well with rich verbose debug terminal information on the Amcrest ProHD 1080P IP Camera IP2M-841B 
https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0145OQTPG/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1 ; sample command:
$ ffplay rtsp://admin:password@192.168.1.XXX:554

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried to follow [these](https://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch05.html) instructions from the Videolan documentation (scroll down to the **Video on demand** section)?

It would be useful if you provide a test rtsp url that you want to stream.

**Edit**: the instructions from the above link are:

> First launch the vlc:
>
> `vlc --ttl 12 -vvv --color -I telnet --telnet-password videolan --rtsp-host 0.0.0.0:5554`
>
> where:
>
> - *12* is the value of the TTL (Time To Live) of your IP packets (which means that the stream will be able to cross 11 routers).
> - *telnet* launches the telnet interface of the vlc.
> - *videolan* is the password to connect to the telnet interface.
> - *0.0.0.0*  is the host address.
> - *5554*  is the port on which you stream.
>
> Then connect to the vlc telnet interface and create the *vod* object:
>
> `new Test vod enabled`
>
> `setup Test input my_video.mpg`
>
> You can access to the stream with:
>
> `vlc rtsp://server:5554/Test`
>
> where *server* is the address of the streaming server (IP or DNS)

Comment: I'm not sure how this should work. It seems to me that this will make me into an rtsp server, but I need to find a client that can communicate with a server that expects some parameters (for authentication)

Answer (score 3):

You may give a try to mplayer.

```
sudo apt-get install mplayer
```

Pass the `rtsp://` URL to mplayer on its command line. There are servers out there that serve files containing a `rtsp://` URL over HTTP, but then serve content in the MMS protocol. This is for compatibility with some older Microsoft players (my memory is hazy over the details), but it breaks clients that believe that RTSP is RTSP and MMS is MMS. If you obtain an `rtsp://` URL that doesn't work at all, try replacing the scheme with `mms://`.

Comment: tried your suggestion but it didn't work.

Comment: tried with mplayer, for some cameras works, for others the sound has noise, continuous beeps. much better with ffplay.